# DRF: Api endpoint does not output all data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My api endpoint created using django rest framework does not output all the serialized data.

**InstagramGeograficsSerializer**

```
class InstagramGeograficsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = InstagramGeoCitySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = InstagramGeograficsAnalitics
        fields = ('city', 'percentage',)
```

**InstagramEthnicSerializer**

```
class InstagramEthnicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InstagramEthnicAnalitics
        fields = ('language', 'percentage',)
```

**InstagramDemographicsSerializer**

```
class InstagramDemographicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InstagramDemographicsAnalitics
        fields = ('age_group', 'gender', 'percentage', 'full_percentage',)
```

**InstagramSerializer**

```
class InstagramSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    geographics = InstagramGeograficsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    demographics = InstagramDemographicsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ethnic = InstagramEthnicSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Instagram
        fields = ('id', 'userid', 'username', 'full_name', 'avatar', 'bio',
                  'website', 'media_count', 'follows_count',
                  'subscriber_count', 'engagement_rate', 'approval_rate',
                  'discussion_rate', 'male_percentage', 'female_percentage', 'geographics', 'demographics', 'ethnic',)
```

my **views.py**

```
class InstagramDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Instagram.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InstagramSerializer
```

And in the end api gives only the data on **ethnic**, and doesn't contain data on **geographics** and **demographics**

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "userid": "3045727148",
            "username": "test2",
            "full_name": "full name",
            "avatar": "",
            "bio": "23",
            "website": "",
            "media_count": 0,
            "follows_count": 0,
            "subscriber_count": 0,
            "engagement_rate": "0.0000000",
            "approval_rate": "0.0000000",
            "discussion_rate": "0.0000000",
            "male_percentage": "0.000",
            "female_percentage": "0.000",
            "ethnic": []
        }
```

**UPD  models Instagram**

```
class Instagram(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_all_instagram', 'Can view all instagram'),
            ('change_all_instagram', 'Can change all instagram'),
        )

    credential = CredentialsField()
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    platform = GenericRelation(Platform,
                               related_query_name='instagram_platform',
                               content_type_field='content_type',
                               object_id_field='object_id')

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.URLField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    media_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    follows_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    subscriber_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    engagement_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=14, decimal_places=7)
    approval_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=14, decimal_places=7)
    discussion_rate = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=14, decimal_places=7)
    male_percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    female_percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

**InstagramEthnicAnalitics**

```
class InstagramEthnicAnalitics(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            (
                'view_all_instagram_ethnic_analytics',
                'Can view all_instagram_ethnic_analytics'
            ),
            (
                'change_all_instagram_ethnic_analytics',
                'Can change all_instagram_ethnic_analytics'
            ),
        )

    instagram = models.ForeignKey(Instagram, related_name='ethnic')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

**InstagramDemographicsAnalitics**

```
class InstagramDemographicsAnalitics(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       #unique_together = (('instagram', 'age_group', 'gender', ),)
        permissions = (
            (
                'view_all_instagram_demographics_analytics', 
                'Can view all_instagram_demographics_analytics'
            ),
            (
                'change_all_instagram_demographics_analytics',
                'Can change all_instagram_demographics_analytics'
            ),
        )
    instagram = models.ForeignKey(Instagram)
    age_group = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='female')
    percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    is_full_gender = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    full_percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Can you show your models? Does Instagram have fields for geographics and demographics?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I update my question, the model does not have these fields, but it also does not contain ethnic

Comment: So where are those fields defined?

Comment: In separate models InstagramGeograficsAnalitics, InstagramDemographicsAnalitics, InstagramEthnicAnalitics each of which has a ForeignKey relationship with Instagram

Comment: But how are those ForeignKeys defined? Show the relevant definitions.

Comment: the question was updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the InstagramSerailizer where to take data for the nested serializer.

So like you did for your "ethnic" (that's why it is returned ) -  you have to specify the related name for the other two fields.

So in the models:

```
class InstagramDemographicsAnalitics(models.Model):
    instagram = models.ForeignKey(Instagram, related_name="demographics")
```

And similarly for the other model ( which you did not include)